# Inserting variable into a table using sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am tring to use a for loop to add data to a table each time with a different id which is the primary key. This is my code and the table is already created

```
x = 1
for x in range(20):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO yourplayers VALUES(? , 'John', 'biggs', 2, 55, 'A', 55)", (x))
    x = x+1
c.execute('SELECT * FROM yourplayers')
conn.commit
print(c.fetchall())
```

It comes up with the error parameters are of an unsupported type but when i get rid of the question and the x in brackets and replace it with just a number it work (if ive stopped it being a primary key or it crashes). Does anyone know what im doing wrong here. The data type where the question mark is is INT

Comment: You are missing a comma, `(x,)`, or use a list, `[x]`. `(x)` is not a tuple, that's just a grouped expression.

Comment: Thank you very much sorry if its been asked before when i looked i just saw similar for mysql